# Google forms stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script, customization, google-forms

I am a student worker and I am learning how to work with google forms. I am trying to build a form for our department I am currently involved in. I have a custom google form it was working for a bit then just stopped.  It is located at http://www.uaf.edu/marketing/intake/. I have the trigger set as onFormSubmit > FromSpreadsheet > onFormSubmit . I am using this code in my script editor and set for onFormSubmit:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var name = e.values[1];
var title = e.values[2];
var department = e.values[3];
var email = e.values[4];
var phone = e.values[5];
var newproject = e.values[6];
var project = e.values[7];
var description = e.values[8];
var descriptcomment = e.values[9];
var audience = e.values[10];
var audiencecomment = e.values[11];
var accomplish = e.values[12];
var result = e.values[13];
var tarday = e.values[14];
var compday = e.values[15];
var infoday = e.values[16];
var chat = e.values[17];
var refer = e.values[18];


// change this address to be the address where you want the notification to go  
var to = "email#1,email#2";
var subject = "MC Intake Form Notification";
var message = "Your Name: " + name + "\n \n";
    message += "Your title: " + title + "\n \n";
    message += "Department: " + department + "\n \n";
    message += "Email: " + email + "\n \n";
    message += "Phone number: " + phone + "\n \n";
    message += "Is this a new project: " + newproject + "\n \n";
    message += "Project title: " + project + "\n \n";
    message += "Project description: " + description + "\n \n";
    message += "Project description comments: " + descriptcomment + "\n \n";
    message += "Who's your audience? " + audience + "\n \n";
    message += "Audience comments " + audiencecomment + "\n \n";
    message += "What are you trying to accomplish? " + accomplish + "\n \n";
    message += "What is the desired result, and what will success look like? " + result + "\n \n";
    message += "What is your targeted start date? " + tarday + "\n \n";
    message += "What is your targeted completion date? " + compday + "\n \n";
    message += "Information about distrbution target dates, what date an event is happening, when you can provide content,etc. " + infoday + "\n \n";
    message += "Are you currently working with anyone in our department? " + chat + "\n \n";
    message += "How were you referred to this form? " + refer + "\n \n";

     var mailOptions = {
         name: name,
         replyTo: email,
     };
    MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, message, mailOptions);
    }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a temporary service outage that cleared itself without user intervention. Others are unlikely to learn from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the ` at the first line?

Also, open the developer tools -> console and see if there are some error messages.

Comment: that is just the backtick from embedding the code here. That is not a part of my code, I am sorry still learning.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. The form is now working again it seems it was a Google doc delay of some kind because now my email is full of a weeks worth of testing emails.